# browser repaints and performance

Tags: html, css, performance, browser

I have a single-page app that uses a lot of CSS3 shadows. The app consists of 8 panels that represent pages. Only 1 panel is visible at a time, while the other 7 are hidden (style display:none;). The user clicks on the menu to move from panel to panel.

Google's Speed Tracer that about 75% of resources is spent on repaints. My question is this: **do browser repaints affect A) only visible elements of the page or B) every element, whether visible or not?**

If it's B then there's not much I can do. If it's A then I could clear the html of the hidden panels and have inner DOM elements for only the visible panel with the goal of reducing repaint time.

Let me know.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of the browser. However, there's no need to render any hidden content, so a smart browser design shouldn't spend much time on them. As an experiment, try taking off all the `display:none` properties and see how it affects performance.

Comment: @Barmar: if I put everything on display:none then none of the UI events will trigger, so of course there'll be no repaint. But that doesn't mean that hidden elements don't repaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to answer performance questions is to perform benchmarks. If you want to know how much performance overhead there is to display:none elements, do the following:

Test 1: Load the page with all the display:none elements, measure the repaint speed.

Test 2: Modify the page so that the display:none elements are removed completely, load this page, and measure the repaint speed.

The difference between the two tests is the repaint overhead of display:none elements. Hopefully it will be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden elements shouldn't repaint. Are you animating the panel? Animating (esp. translating) an element that has shadows really puts the load on repainting. Also, the bigger the shadow, the longer it takes to repaint. I haven't done exact measurements, just drawing from personal experience; the 'jank' gets pretty obvious pretty fast, at least in older machines. Maybe try a background, data-uri image instead.